# XCTestCase Error

Tags: ios, swift, uitest

I'm trying to run unit tests in my application, however at the time of running it gives the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNNTX.png)

in my code I already added : @testable import MyProject, but it still does not work

Comment: Have you added component you are trying to test into TestTarget? Select file, first tab on the right side.